# Taquicardia é mesma coisa de Ataque cardíaco?

Tags: significado

Sempre achei que "taquicardia" seria uma forma reduzida de falar "ataque cardíaco", e ainda não sei exatamente.

Taquicardia é mesma coisa de ataque cardíaco? A palavra **taquicardia** surgiu de **ataque cardíaco**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É uma coincidência. Não há relação, nem semântica (como mostra a resposta do @Peixoto), nem etimológica entre "taquicardia" e "ataque cardíaco". Taquicardia vem do grego *tachys*, rápido, e *cardis*, coração (confira, por exemplo, "taquímetro", medidor de velocidade). "Ataque" tem outra origem, provavelmente germânica (*stak*, que também está na origem de "estaca"), e não tem relação com velocidade.

Answer (score 2):

Taquicardia é um aumento do batimento cardíaco, onde o normal é entre 60 e 100 batimentos por minuto. Já um Ataque Cardíaco (Infarto no termo técnico) é quando há parada da circulação de sangue para uma parte do coração.

Pode ver a definição de [Taquicardia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taquicardia) e [Ataque Cardíaco](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infarto_agudo_do_mioc%C3%A1rdio) na wikipedia.